# The use of (javascript:) in Href attributes

Tags: javascript, html

Please I have seen some people use this "javascript:" in some href  attribute of an a tag. Please my question  is what is the purpose of that in the in the a tag. Thus does that ensure that the clicking on the a tag sends the function of the click to javascript to handle instead of the **DOM OR WHAT IS THE REAL PURPOSE OF IT.** (  JAVASCRIPT:)

Comment: The `javascript:` protocol evaluates and executes the proceding string as JavaScript, e.g. `href="javascript:alert('hello');"`. It's rarely used; rather, events are handled centrally in a dedicated .js file.

Answer (score 3):

In short: it executes JavaScript when clicking on the link:

```html
<a href="javascript:console.log('Click!')">Click me please!</a>
```